# CSS acting weird

Tags: css

i have the following css code:

```
.tag {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #444;
}

.tag:hover {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #666;
}
```

aside from the background color, and one having the display:inline, there is no difference, correct? Well when the .tag div comes into existance, it has white text but no background color. it also has a 12pt font size and no padding. however, it looks perfectly the way its supposed to when I hover over it. Can anyone tell me why its doing this?

Comment: Try adding !important to the end of your property values on the .tag { }

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. would be nice if you could put this in an answer so i can accept it

Comment: There you go, I put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use !important

Answer (score 5):

there will be no different if you only have these 2 classes in your css file/scriptlet.
but it will be different if you have more than 2 and mixed with other classes as well.

your .tag might be overidden by other class
I'd debug it using firefox + firebug. This tool will show you which css class/properties is voeridden

Comment: I was just about to suggest the same. Using the !important property is a just a bandaid/cover-up solution. You need to debug your CSS and figure out what style is overriding the code in question. Otherwise, you're just letting your code get disorganized.

Comment: @Calvin !important is not always a cover up solution.